# Eggless brownie, cake, dessert recipes

Tags: cake, dessert, brownies

I am looking to find recipes for desserts, specifically brownies and cakes although others are greatly appreciated, that do not contain eggs.

Is there a sort of egg substitute that works just as well as eggs in all foods?

Comment: Here are some questions that may help you: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14025/are-there-any-vegetarian-friendly-egg-substitutes-that-can-be-used-in-cakes and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53450/how-to-substitute-in-baking-so-the-result-is-both-egg-and-gluten-free

Comment: Hello Elthuen! Our site does not do recipe swapping at all, so that part would be off topic. As for the "general substitute" part, it's already been asked and answered on the site. But you are on a good way when trying to find complete recipes, because there is no general substitute and using some of those linked in the other question usually require tedious tweaking until the recipe gets acceptable. You can probably find some good and tested recipes in recipe databases. Sorry that I had to close your first q, but I think the duplicate original and Johannas links will be interesting for you.